Compiling fortran source files in a python project upon installation
I have a python project with fortran routines. I prefer not to distribute the pre-compiled binaries (*.so files). I want the compilation to be automated during the installation.
So far I have a Makefile to compile the fortran sources with f2py. But I feel like the user will have to manually use the make command afterwards.
How to do it? To setup my project, I use a setup.cfg file.

Have you looked at https://textbooks.cs.ksu.edu/cc410/ii-gui/15-releases/07-building-wheel/

I think you have 2 mistakes here. "I prefer not to distribute the pre-compiled binaries (.so files).*" That's mistake 1: people prefer to install binaries; only when binaries are not available they reluctantly agree to compile. "So far I have a Makefile to compile" Here I see mistake 2: you should stop running make yourself and instead automate your own installation.
